# Informatica Database driver error with SQL stmt Select

Tags: informatica, data-masking

Facing below error while executing the job in informatica TDM.

SQL error Table or view does not exist
Database driver error
Function name : Execute
SQL stmt : select t0.col name1 as "col name1", t0.col name2 as "col name2" from tablename t0
Oracle fatal error
Prepare failed
Rolling back all the targets due to fatal session error

Comment: Does the user mentioned in informatica oracle connection has SELECT access ? Can you try like SELCT ... FROM schema.table_name t0 ?

Comment: Yes. Having Select access. Able to fetch the table if mentioned along with schema name

Comment: so is the issue resolved? If not, can you please post actual select query from session log? We are missing something i think. And pls ensure 1. the user is Informatica using to connect to DB is same user you are testing with. 2. You are able to issue SELECT * from schema.table using that user 3. In informatica SQL, you mentioned schemaname. tablename in SQL overwrite.

Comment: No. Issue is not resolved.

Comment: select t0.USR_ID as "USR_ID", t0.PHN_NO as "PHN_NO" from USR_INFO t0

Comment: I have added schema name to the source table. How we can add to the target table.

Comment: there is an option in session > mapping > target. Edit session, go to 'Mapping' tab. Then select the target, go to properties section on right pane. scroll down and find 'table name prefix'. Mention your schema name there. Wish i can add a screenshot but i cant here.

Comment: If my solution works, shall i mark this as answer?

Comment: Yes plz. Thank you

Comment: Did it :), thank you too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in session > mapping > target. Edit session, go to 'Mapping' tab. Then select the target, go to properties section on right pane. scroll down and find 'table name prefix'. Mention your schema name there. [image]